# UV map really small in uv editing?

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

UV's appearing too small in editing?
[image: UV's appearing too small in editing?]

The UV's appear entirely to small, and so it makes the texture to big.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To successfully unwrap your mesh, first, you need to add seams to it, so you can projectile your 3D mesh into a 2D plane. [Here is a beginner friendly tutorial from Andrew Price](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBUfMKKZDo&ab_channel=BlenderGuru), but you can also find a lot of useful other tutorials.

Also, you can use the built-in "Smart UV Project" function in Blender to automatically unwrap your model based on an angle value you give.

Another thing that I want to advise you is to have a good topology with good edge flow for your mesh, which will be important and it'll make your life easier if you want to rig and animate your character later.

Comment: I will see if this works, Thanks!

Comment: Yo can also select (A)ll in the UV editor and (S)caling to see what's going on.